# Are the roots of $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$ always the addition identity and multiplication identity for any field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are the roots of polynomial $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$ always the addition identity $0$ and multiplication identity $1$ for any field $F$? If not, anyone can help give a counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

In a field, you have the distributative laws:
$$a(b+c) = ab+ac$$
So, we can apply that to your polynomial:
$$\lambda^2-\lambda = \lambda(\lambda-1)$$
Now, for $\lambda(\lambda-1) = 0$, we have one of the two productands must be zero (fields don't have zero divisors, so there can't be $a,b\neq 0$ such that $ab = 0$).

Now, this means that either $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda-1 = 0$.
In the first case we have that $\lambda = 0$, the additive identity.
In the second case, we can add one ot both sides to get that $\lambda -1+1 = 1$, then use that inverses cancel to get that $\lambda = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

$\lambda^2-\lambda=0$ is the same as $\lambda(\lambda-1)=0$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity. Fields have no zero-divisors, so $\lambda =0$ or $\lambda-1=0$. So yes, the only solutions are $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$.

Comment: This is because a field demands that multiplication must distribute over addition?

Comment: That is one property that was used (to say $\lambda^2-\lambda=\lambda(\lambda-1)$. The really important one is that fields have no zero-divisors besides zero itself.

Comment: For instance, in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_6$, $3^2-3=9-3=3-3=0$, yet $3$ is neither $0$ nor $1$. We see that $3^2-3=3(3-1)=3\cdot 2$, which is $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ even though neither $2$ nor $3$ is $0$. So the result fails because $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has zero divisors, namely $2$ and $3$.